# Sequential celery task execution

Tags: python, django, celery

I have a heavy celery task that parses data from XML files to the DB and sometimes I'm having troubles with media files because of celery tasks running multiple parsers, which I don't need. So I want to know is there any way to do this sequentially? I mean I need some kind of delay after every successful parsing or something like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Celery has a Chains concept where you can link tasks together so that they execute once their preceding task completes successfully.

https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/canvas.html#chains

Comment: So I just have to add 'apply_async' before calling the task?

Comment: No, in that first example apply_async() is calling the initial task https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/calling.html#basics , the link is a keyword argument passed into apply_async(). Chain is a special signature making the linking of tasks more easy: https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/reference/celery.html#celery.chain

Comment: yes, I get it, but I have 1 celery task that executes several times, will it work with only 1 task?

Comment: Yes, you can chain the same task, multiple times and with different arguments. The docs I've linked to have examples of this nature.